# R Replace header by names in row

Tags: r, header, dataframe

I would like to replace the header of a data.frame by a header in the first row.
The data has been imported with read.xls(). Reading in the original file again is unfortunately no option.

```
     bad header    here
1    new    header2   here
2    58 3.222     50
3    25 10.000    40
4    5  0.847     152.5
5   15  1.633     98
```

The result should look like this:

```
    new header2   here
1   58  3.222     50
2   25  10.000    40
3   5   0.847     152.5
4   15  1.633     98
```

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is called my.data.frame just assign row 1 to the header and then delete row 1

```
    #assign row 1 names to the header          
    names(my.data.frame) <- as.character(my.data.frame[1,])

    #delete the first row
    my.data.frame <- my.data.frame[2:nrow(my.data.frame),]
```

Comment: But the OP specifically said he no longer has access to the source file.

Comment: The combination of names and as.character was exactly what I needed. Thanks. @carl This solution works without rereading the dataset!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf", you can try something like this:

```
df2 <- setNames(mydf[-1, ], mydf[1, ])
```

However, your data will all be character or factor depending on how they were initially read in.

```
str(df2)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ new    : chr  "58" "25" "5" "15"
#  $ header2: chr  "3.222" "10.000" "0.847" "1.633"
#  $ here   : chr  "50" "40" "152.5" "98"
```

You can convert that as follows:

```
df2[] <- lapply(df2, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x)))
str(df2)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ new    : int  58 25 5 15
#  $ header2: num  3.222 10 0.847 1.633
#  $ here   : num  50 40 152 98
df2
#   new header2  here
# 2  58   3.222  50.0
# 3  25  10.000  40.0
# 4   5   0.847 152.5
# 5  15   1.633  98.0
```